# How to run dreamweaver local testing server with html page

Tags: google-chrome, shortcuts, dreamweaver

I have an HTML page that I'm working on and I run the live view by hitting <kbd>F12</kbd> on the keyboard to open up in my default browser.

What I want is to open this same page (that runs on local server) directly from Dreamweaver in the browser. So instead of saving the changes in Dreamweaver and then opening my browser and typing in the address bar `localhost/myProjectName/thePageImCurrentlyWorkingOn` I just want to save the page in Dreamweaver and then hit a shortcut button that opens the page in the browser with the local server.

PS. My default browser is Google chrome and I use XAMPP for my local server.

Answer (score 0):

To view your DW page in the Chrome browser, you can either go to the menu under File, and chose to "Preview in Browser".  If you don't see Chrome in your list, from this menu chose to "Edit menu list" to add Chrome.
There is also a "globe" icon in the lower right corner of the DW interface which gives the option to "Preview in Browser" as well.
In order to make F12 open the Chrome browser, open DW preferences and choose "Preview in Browser" and add Chrome as the browser to open with F12.
Hope this helps!